# How do 1080p text and computer sources look on a 4K Display?

Tags: tv, scaling

I've never seen a monitor that can display text in its non-native resolution without looking fuzzy. While Video, Images, and Games look decent, you can tell that scaling is occurring. Now, there are people that say if your source is some multiple of the display (for example 960x540 on a 1080p display), it will look perfect; which in my experience is incorrect, especially for text.

My question therefore, is comparing a 4K TV to a 1080p TV for a given 1080p source. Am I correct in assuming, the 1080p TV will do *better* than the 4K TV at displaying the 1080p signal? (assuming again, text)

Comment: I think your answer depends on your specific hardware.  I don't think working in the hypothetical is going to yield any objectivity.  No down vote here; just a thought.

Comment: Multiple choice - Can 4K TVs perform 1080p  upscaling:
 (A) perfectly, including text  (B) imperfectly, better for video, worse for Text (C) worse for both, quality varies depending on TV's internal scaler

Answer (score 2):

Nope. I routinely run 720p and 1080p video on my 4k displays and it looks fine.

*Text* actually tends to scale well in most cases. Text is mostly vectors. Vectors scale nicely. I do use a 150% UI scaling, and websites, and ebooks look *glorious*.

That said, I tend to do any upscaling or resizing at the *source*. Madvr does an awesome job at upscaling 4k with a good video card on MPC, and 720p videos look *fine* on vlc or a default renderer. Actual 4k stuff looks *better*, but even when my second monitor was 720p or 1080p, a *good* 4k display beats the crap out of it.

Setting a 4k display to 1080p does look a bit bad but after a 4k screen *1080p* 
looks bad.I do run that for linux and it looks no worse than a 1080p screen would.

Video will look *no worse*.

So. *Don't upscale* at the display. Set your environment up to work at 4k. at 27 inches/4k, I set UI scaling to 150% - some people like 120%. With a *bigscreen* tv, you might not need that at all. Set *text* sizes - since text resizes correctly. Let your *video player* resample if needed, and if you can, try getting a renderer that specialises in that.

Don't buy a 4k panel and set it to 1080p tho. Its a little like buying a a sports car to use at a job site.

Comment: good information there, but that wasn't the question. The assumption is the source will be unable to support more than 1080p output. Think of a conference room with multiple inputs. Sometimes, we will use 4K sources, but many times, the laptops connected will only support 1080p maximum.

Comment: Oh, I actually do what you say as well. Edited the question. Still seems a bit of a waste - one of my screens does 4K as a secondary screen to my primary system, and 1080p for 2 other systems

Comment: One could conclude then, that you're better off buying a 1080p TV if all your sources are 1080p, and mostly text/productivity (ignoring future-proofing). If I was consulting for a firm wanting to buy dozens of screens for their conference rooms, I'd end up with that conclusion. It could be 5+ years before a critical mass of laptops in circulation support 4K output.

Comment: Pretty much. And well, in this scenario, and considering prices, That's not a good idea. Or spend what you would spend on a low end 4k display and get a  lowe end 1440p IPS display.I do believe the tipping point for 4k hardware is the *next generation* since even onboard video will support 3 4k displays for non gaming purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're watching 1080p video and you aren't used to actual 4K content, it'll look just fine. If you are used to 4K content, you may note a slight blurriness since the 1080p content is being upscaled to 4K and there's no way to perfectly add the additional pixels other than through guessing (via techniques such as interpolation).

If you're comparing 1080p content side-by-side on a 4K display and a 1080p display, it's unlikely that you'll notice a difference. (The 1080p content is scaled up on the 4K display so may look slightly less pixelated or slightly blurry depending on how you perceive things.)

That said, I find the blurring minimal for video. For games it's a slightly more noticeable (but not distracting) because of the excessively sharp silhouettes you get from 3D rendered content.

Comment: Reading between the lines, text will look worse? For instance, using a 4K monitor for productivity with  a 1080p source?

Comment: @cloneman It depends on the source of the text. For example, in Windows, it'll appear sharper, but about half the size you're used to. (There are some settings for that. Certain applications don't support this but Windows takes tries to take care of it. Those are definitely blurry.) For text embedded in video, it'll look pretty close to what you'd get in 1080p.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, if you're going to do that, add a comment saying why so that the issue can be addressed.

Comment: I disagree with that - different scenario; if you're using Windows or Mac to scale, the TV will see your computer as a 4K source and will not perform any scaling of its own.

Comment: @cloneman If your TV is modern and hooked up to your computer (say by HDMI) it will report to your computer its compatible resolutions. The computer will use whatever it sees as best, usually the highest one and then try to provide a source matching that. For 1080p content on a 4K screen, this will be about 1/4 the area of your screen. If you maximize the window (or make fullscreen) you end up with upscaled content. If you compare a 1080p display with a 4K display, both with the same physical dimensions (e.g.: 42"), with 1080p fullscreen content, the difference should be negligible.